# How to describe texture of the snow when you can make snowballs?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the proper way to describe the texture of the snow ?

I "brain farted" when I was trying to explain the texture of the snow to my friend; he/she ended up saying:

> "It's too dry for making snowballs".

I believe you can describe the snow as dry/powder, but what is the correct term to explain the texture when you CAN make snowballs/snowman other shapes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In my youth we simply said "it's good packing" to refer to snow that was fit for snowballs.

Comment: @JimMack: Exactly the phrase I would have used 75 years ago in northern Illinois. By the same token, it was hard shovelling.

Comment: , I'll try to add these to my list, though I find it hard for other (fellow foreigners) to understand what I mean, when I try to use expression like "Good'ol packing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the opposite of *dry snow*: **wet snow**

> Only **wet snow**, containing up to 50 percent liquid water, is good
> for making snowballs, and this needs temperatures around freezing
> point. [Karen Hill; "Why Is Wet Snow Better For Making Snowballs That
> Dry Powdery Snow and Why Is Temperature an Important Factor?", zippyfacts.com](https://zippyfacts.com/why-is-wet-snow-better-for-making-snowballs-that-dry-powdery-snow-and-why-is-temperature-an-important-factor/)

> Unlike **wet snow**, dry snow is powdery and cannot easily be formed
> into snowballs or snowmen. [Eric DeRoche; "The Important Difference
> Between Wet Snow and Dry Snow", compuweather.com](https://www.compuweather.com/the-important-difference-between-wet-snow-and-dry-snow/)

> Ever tried to build a snowman with powdery snow, only to find that it
> just won't stick? Or have you noticed how much harder it is to shovel
> sticky snow compared to when it's in its light, fluffy form?
>
> The cause for these differences is the surface temperature. When
> surface temperatures are just above freezing, snow can melt slightly,
> adding more moisture and creating heavy, **wet snow**. When surface
> temperatures are below freezing, you get powder.[Samantha-Rae Tuthill;
> "The Difference Between **Wet** and Powdery Snow", accuweather.com](https://www.accuweather.com/en/weather-news/the-difference-between-wet-and-powdery-snow/171812)

Comment: Aaaaargh, **wet**. Thanks for your help.